# How to flatten multiple shapes in Sketch App?

Tags: layers, shapes, sketch-app

How to flatten more than two combine shape in Sketch App?

The image below is an example as I'm trying to do a whole shape flatten and make a single shape, how can I do?

[image]

Comment: your answer is here too: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/34879/how-can-i-connect-two-disjoint-paths-in-sketch-app

Answer (score 2):

> **VERSION 1**
>
> 1. Select all your files
> 2. Click on Union ( Layer>Combine>Union) or ⌥⌘U
> 3. Layer>Paths>**Flatten** or click the icon on the top menu bar
>
> **VERSION 2**
>
> 1. Select all your files
> 2. On your top menu bar there is **Create Symbol** click that.
> 3. Press Insert on top left menu bar and in symbols you will find your
>      shape as a symbol which you can use.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm trying to do whole shape in single shape. In single shape it will be easy to change colour or whatever do.

Comment: Version 1 at least doesn't work, just gives me an error, "The shape you are trying to flatten requires more than one subpath to be rendered" (duh, that's why I'm flattening them…). Also by 'files' I assume you mean 'layers'.

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes. Version 1 should be the correct answer for what's being asked in the question. Version 2 is technically not flattening anything, just grouping the shapes. So if you export an SVG for example it would export as if they were separate shapes, not a compound shape.

Answer (score 1):

I am newbie in sketch.

I am trying to figure out how to create the line icons could use "Shared style" just like what you want to do.

Now, I still Stuck in how to create line icons with shape(consisted by paths, just like your bottle is made by 2 paths.)

Anyway, when I saw your question, it give me an idea.

Did you try just drag those 4 sub-path into Bottle Shape directly?

My step is as below:
1. Drag 4 sub-path in to shape
[image: Drag 4 sub-path in to shape]

2. 4 sub-path are in the shape group now
   [image: 4 sub-path are in the shape group now]
3. Then Change "union" to "none".
4. Now you can use "Shared style" to change colour or border, shadow...

Maybe it's not correct way, but I really hope it can give you some ideas.

By Vin

Answer (score 0):

It's annoyingly simple. All you have to do is drag the sublayers into the same compound path layer, so they're all at the same level.

I found this thread because I couldn't figure it out, then tried that and it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, it is `Layer` > `Combine` > `Flatten`